# Reverse engineering getting function prototype

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I'm trying to get the prototype of an asm function to call it from my injected c++ dll.

Here is the function:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
PUSH -1
PUSH Program.0151A5BB
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0]
PUSH EAX
SUB ESP,0F8
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[167D380]
XOR EAX,EBP
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14],EAX
PUSH EBX
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDI
PUSH EAX
LEA EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C]
MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],EAX
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10],ESP
MOV EDI,EDX
MOV ESI,ECX
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],0
CMP ESI,0FFFF
JE SHORT Program.0117DFC9
CALL Program.01205130
MOV ECX,82
CALL Program.012F2AE0
MOV ECX,ESI
CALL Program.012F3050
MOV ECX,EDI
CALL Program.012F3050
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
CALL Program.012F2EA0
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
CALL Program.012F3050
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]
CALL Program.012F2EA0
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]
CALL Program.012F2EA0
MOV CL,1
CALL Program.012F39B0
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],-1
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-C]
MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],ECX
POP ECX
POP EDI
POP ESI
POP EBX
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]
XOR ECX,EBP
CALL Program.014BB1AC
MOV ESP,EBP
POP EBP
RETN
```

And here is an example of a call to this function

```
JMP Program.001CDD83
CALL Program.000930A0
MOV ECX,EAX
CALL Program.0024EC10
PUSH EAX                                 ; /Arg4
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-168]              ; |Arg3
PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EDI+8]                ; |Arg2
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-160]              ; |Arg1
MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-16C]           ; |
MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-164]           ; |
CALL Program.0006DF80                      ; \<---- TARGET FUNCTION
ADD ESP,10
JMP Program.001CDD83
TEST EAX,800
JE SHORT Program.001CDF6D
TEST ESI,ESI
JE Program.001CDD83
CMP ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[72202C]
JE Program.001CDD83
CMP ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[584684]
```

By the function call I was able to deduce that is a **__fastcall** function since it uses the **EDX** and **ECX** registers and it takes 4 additional parameters via stack.

Checking the stack and the registers in the moment of the call I could determinate that all 6 parameters are numbers.

Here is a picture of the state just in the function call.

[image: Registry and stack at the moment of the call]

With all this in mind I made this definition

```
typedef void(__fastcall *_programFunction)(DWORD ECX, DWORD EDX, DWORD param1, DWORD param2, DWORD param3, DWORD param4);
```

And it calls the function and the function **works** in my target program but my DLL **crashes** displaying this error:

"*Debug Error!
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.*"

I'm pretty sure this is a *__fastcall* function since is the only one that prioritises *EDX* and *ECX* over the stack. Plus the caller function isn't cleaning the stack, that's another hint for *__fastcall*

There is any trick to deduce the function protptype from asm code?

There is something wrong with my thinking?

Thank you!!

**EDIT:**

I checked what  **mainactual** said

> ADD ESP, 10 after your function call seems more __cdecl to me: the caller cleans the stack. If it were a __fastcall you should find RET 10 at the end. –

and it works when I add manualy the first two parameters to `ECX` and `EDX` registers.

like this

```
typedef void(__cdecl *_targetFunction)(DWORD param1, DWORD param2, DWORD param3, DWORD param4);


_targetFunction fcall= (_targetFunction)(ADD_TARGET_FUNCTION);
__asm
        {
            mov ECX, ECX_PARAM
            mov EDX, EDX_PARAM
        }
fcall(param1, pram2, param3, param4);
```

Thank you! but why do I have to do this? There is any way to set the registers automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: "all 6 parameters are numbers" that's interesting. As opposed to what?

Comment: They may also be char arrays, then the definition should be `char* param`.

Comment: How do you tell numbers from non-numbers? Do numbers have the green bit set?

Comment: `ADD ESP, 10` after your function call seems more `__cdecl` to me: the caller cleans the stack. If it were a `__fastcall` you should find `RET 10` at the end.

Comment: But two of the parameters are sent by `ECX` and `EDX`, `__cdecl` doesn't use registers right?

Comment: "if a compiler knows that it controls all the callers of a function, then it can modify the calling convention as long as the modified convention still observes the operating system rules." from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150128-00/?p=44813

Answer (score 0):

Due to optimizations, you will occasionally find functions which do not perfectly match the normal calling conventions.

In this situation, the solution is to use inline assembly which you have already accomplished in your question:

```
typedef void(__cdecl *_targetFunction)(DWORD param1, DWORD param2, DWORD param3, DWORD param4);


_targetFunction fcall= (_targetFunction)(ADD_TARGET_FUNCTION);
__asm
        {
            mov ECX, ECX_PARAM
            mov EDX, EDX_PARAM
        }
fcall(param1, pram2, param3, param4);
```

Sometimes that's just the way it goes.